# Why does my iterator variable keep resetting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array populated with numbers. I want to display a new number every 5 seconds in an `alert()` popup. What I have appears to be working for the most part, but it resets before showing the number 3. At first it shows 1, then it shows 2, then it shows 1 again. I can't figure it out. I would like to maintain this syntax for the most part if I can. I just don't understand why `counter` keeps resetting to 0.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var maxLoops = Number(arr.length);
var counter = -1;

(function next() {
    if (counter++ > maxLoops);
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(arr[counter]);
        next();
    }, 5000);
})();
```

Comment: it works fine for me http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/vKBNYZ

Comment: I could not reproduce the error.  Is this part of a larger program?  Perhaps `counter` is being reset elsewhere in the code.

Comment: The `if` has a semicolon at the end, that entire line *only* increments counter. `setTimeout` is always called.

Comment: You probably meant to *not* have that semicolon at the end of the line and you probably wanted `if (counter++ < maxLoops) { setTimeout... }`.

Comment: Note that all of the timers and the main execution line share one instance of `counter`. Nothing prevents it from changing between the time you call `setTimeout` and the time it calls the timeout callback.

Comment: [Cleaner way to do self repeating timeouts](https://jsfiddle.net/zeups331/)

Comment: Counter behavior is very strange. Are you sure this code only executes once? If you can not find where counter is reset, try to wrap it into IIFE.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the value of `counter` may change between setting the timer and calling the anonymous function within it.  To alleviate this problem, the value of `counter` must be passed into the timer function.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var maxLoops = Number(arr.length) - 1;
var counter = -1;

(function next() {
    if (counter++ >= maxLoops) return;
    setTimeout((function (c) {
        return (function() {
            alert(arr[c]);
            next();
        });
    })(counter), 5000);
})();
```

Personally, I would like to write this as follows:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

(function next(counter) {
    if (counter < arr.length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(arr[counter]);
            next(counter + 1);
        }, 5000);
    }
})(0);
```

This implementation ensures `next` has a local copy of `counter`, whose value does not change while the function runs, so that the timeout function uses the correct `counter` value each time.

If the page is getting refreshed (for whatever reason), you could also set all the timeout functions together with the following "one-liner":

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.forEach(function (e, i) {
    setTimeout(function () { alert(e); }, 5000 * (i + 1));
});
```

Comment: Okay something you're saying is correct. You missed a semi-colon, but once I added it, I was able to get to 3 before it reset. I was also able to get to 4 once before it reset. But most of the time it reset after 3.

EDIT: Nevermind. This doesn't help at all. It gets to 3 if you set the duration to 1 second, but it resets back to 0 after 2 if you set the duration to 5 seconds.

Comment: Could you provide more context around this code?  In which environment are you running it?  Is there a chance that another part of your code is resetting `counter`, seeing as it is a global variable?

Comment: This may not necessarily solve the problem, but it does solve obvious problems with the implementation in the question. This code fixes your `if` problem and captures the value of `counter` (as `c`) in the `setTimeout`, preserving the value until the timer callback occurs.

Comment: I'm using this code in a browser extension (TamperMonkey to be exact) and I think it's being reset by the `@match` variable in the extension header. So when the page refreshes, the extension resets the script. I should probably use a session or something for `counter`.

Comment: If the page is refreshing, then the script will indeed restart.  Have you tried setting timeout functions all together?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. [Would it be possible to use this to achieve constant increment even after page reload?](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/js-session/index.html)

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the changes I suggested.  If this does not solve your problem, you could consider the session library.  Perhaps you could share what you're trying to achieve?  There might be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constantly resetting the counter, just keep increasing it and using the `%` operator. For example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5],
    counter = 0

setInterval(function() {
    alert(arr[counter++%arr.length])
}, 5000)
```

The meat of the code is the following line:

```
alert(
  counter++ // Will increase variable after statement
  % // Modulus Operator: Basically Remainder
  arr.length // The length of the array
)
```

[Read about remainder on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you do this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var maxLoops = Number(arr.length);
var counter = 0;

(function next() {
    if (counter >= maxLoops) return;
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(arr[counter++]);
        next();
    }, 5000);
})();
```

You need to put the `return` statement to indicate the function must finish, otherwise, it will continue with the setTimeout and the counter incremented value.